# MultiautoCompleteTextView ime keyabord does not show suggestions

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm using `MultiautoCompleteTextView`. it works perfect. strange problem though that some devices do not show keyboard suggestions:

**Using Nexus 5**
[image: Using nexus 5]

**Using galaxy s6**
[image: Using galaxy s6]

*Some Code*

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_write_text_editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_editor_margin_top"
    android:gravity="start|top"
    android:hint="@string/enter_text"
    android:imeOptions="normal"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoComplete"
    android:maxLength="1200"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

public void setupEditorBox (View view) {
    mEditTextBox = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_write_text_editText);
    mEditTextBox.setThreshold(1);
    mEditTextBox.setTokenizer(new HashTagTokenizer());
    mEditTextBox.setAdapter(new HashTagAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.auto_complete_tag_item));
    mEditTextBox.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Mmm, I think the code you provided is not enough

Comment: please let me know what else is required and i will gladly supply it (-:. the `Adapter` itself is with no connection. i've supplied the xml configuration + the `TextView` code initialization

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I read it wrong, I thought you were talking about suggestions on the edit text itself, not those from the keyboard. I'll fav this question and see what happens because now I'm curious

Comment: (-:...cheers. notice that it's not working on *some* of the devices.. the pictures attached show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Nexus Devices you can fix it setting the InputType.

```
mEditTextBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

At least with a simple ArrayAdapter and the MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer, setting the InputType fix this issue.